# Is the primary key stored implicitly in other keys in mysql myisam engine?

Tags: mysql, indexing, myisam

My problem: imagine a table with millions of rows, like

```
CREATE TABLE a {
id INT PRIMARY KEY,
column2..,
column3..,
many other columns..
..
INDEX (column2);
```

and a query like this:

```
SELECT id FROM a WHERE column2 > 10000 LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 5000;
```

My question: does mysql only use the index "column2" (so the primary key id is implicitly stored as a reference in other indexes), or does it have to fetch all rows to get also the id, which is selected for output? In that case the query should be much faster with a key declared as:

```
INDEX column2(column2, id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An index on `column2` is required. Your suggestion with id in the index will prevent table scans and should be very efficient.

Further more it is faster to do this assuming that `column2` is a continuous sequence:

```
SELECT id FROM a WHERE column2 > 15000 LIMIT 1000;
```

This is because to work with the offset it would just have to scan the next 5000 records (MySQL does not realize that you are actually offsetting `column2`).

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question (prevent table scans, which seems to be very slow in my case). Your suggestion to omit offsetting does not work for me, because the data in column2 is not a continuous sequence.

Comment: Ah, too bad for that part. You could record the last found value from your offset range so that when the user would ask for the next offset you can use the `column2 > max of previous offset` to keep it a bit more efficient. (So your offset is still there, but on every page next, you use the previous retrieved max(column2))

Answer (score 4):

Short answer:  No.

Long answer:

MyISAM, unlike InnoDB, has a "pointer" to the data in the leaf node of each index, including that `PRIMARY KEY`.

So, `INDEX(col2)` is essentially `INDEX(col2, ptr)`.  Ditto for `INDEX(id)` being `INDEX(id, ptr)`.

The "pointer" is either a byte offset into the .MYD file (for `DYNAMIC`) or record number (for `FIXED`).  In either case, the pointer leads to a "seek" into the .MYD file.

The pointer defaults to a 6-byte number, allowing for a huge number of rows.  It can be changed by a setting, either for saving space or allowing an even bigger number of rows.

For your particular query, `INDEX(col2, id)` is optimal and "covering".  It is better than `INDEX(col2)` for MyISAM, but they are equivalent for InnoDB, since InnoDB implicitly has the PK in each secondary index.

The query will have to scan at least 5000+1000 rows, at least in the index's BTree.

Note that InnoDB's `PRIMARY KEY` is clustered with the data, but MyISAM's `PRIMARY KEY` is a separate BTree, just like other secondary indexes.

You really should consider moving to InnoDB; there is virtually no reason to use MyISAM today.